# How to get elements with id = "id[{{$index}}]" in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a blade form that is shown the accounts already saved in db
because someone can add a lot of accounts, I added a `foreach` in that first, and then added a variable `$i` that gets `index` to element's `id`
like this

```
<div style="display: none;">{{ $i = 0 }}</div>
        @if(!empty($accounts))
            @foreach($accounts as $account)
<span class="text-primary number h6 font-weight-bold" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addDirect{{$i}}">دایرکت اتوماتیک</span><span></span>
<!--add Direct Modal -->
<form action="{{ route('update_automatic_direct') }}" method="post" id="frm-add-direct[{{$i}}]">
    <div class="modal fade" id="addDirect{{$i}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addmodaldirect" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="addmodaldirect"> دایرکت اتوماتیک</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                         <input type="text" name="direct_page_id" id="direct-page-id[{{$i}}]">
                         <label for="direct-count" class="col-sm-5 col-form-label font-weight-bold h6 pr-0">حداکثر دایرکت در ساعت:</label>
                         <div class="col-sm-5 pr-0">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="direct-count[{{$i}}]" name="direct_count" placeholder="0">
                         </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                         <label class="font-weight-bold h6">متن پیام</label>
                         <textarea id="new-direct[{{$i}}]" class="form-control directText" name="directText" type="textarea" rows="5"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="save_direct" id="add-Direct" value="ذخیره">
                     <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                     <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{{ $i + 1 }}
```

@endforeach
@endif

Now this is my script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#frm-add-direct').on('submit' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var post = $(this).attr('method');
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type : post,
        url : url,
        data : data,
        dataTy: 'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            $("#addDirect").modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Now my question is, I have many form tags, how can I find the user that was clicked in order to change it. Because I also need the `id` for updating the record in database.

Comment: ID's must be unique in a page. Use a class, instead.

Comment: @ReSedano my IDs are unique, because all of them has [index]

Comment: IDs can't be an array you should use the braket array notation on the names `direct_text[]`, `direct_count[]` etc ...

Comment: @simonecosci he has a form per each item, so he will only submit a single item not a array of items

Comment: @madalinivascu omg you are right <form> tag is inside the loop ... i did'n see it ... forget my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class for your form

```
<form class="submitForm" action="{{ route('update_automatic_direct') }}" method="post" id="frm-add-direct[{{$i}}]">
```

change your input to

```
<input type="text" name="direct_page_id" id="direct-page-id[{{$i}}]" value="{{$i}}">
```

use that form class to submit your data

```
 $('.submitForm').on('submit' , function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var post = $(this).attr('method');
        var form = $(this);
        var id = form.find('[name="direct_page_id"]').val();//get the id of the element based on the submitted form


        console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            type : post,
            url : url,
            data : data,
            dataTy: 'json',
            success:function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                form.find("#addDirect").modal('hide');
            }
        });
    });
```

I suggest you better use the actual id of the accounts that you have stored in the database

Comment: @Rezash your original script was attaching the event to the `#frm-add-direct` id, which didn't match your forms because they each have their own id. Using a class attaches the event handler to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to write the id like that id="frm-add-direct[{{$i}}]", just use data attributes instead.

in jquery you should use data attribute to save id's or any kind of data in your html.
so you can give a common class and data attribute for the id to each form like that:

```
<form class="add-form" data-id="[{{$i}}]" action="{{ route('update_automatic_direct') }}" method="post" id="frm-add-direct">
```

and get the clicked form id by this script:

```
$('.add-form').on('submit' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id'); // here is the clicked form id
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var post = $(this).attr('method');

    console.log(data, id, url, post);

    $.ajax({
        type : post,
        url : url,
        data : data,
        dataTy: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
            $("#addDirect").modal('hide');
        }
    });
});
```